# Wordpress - Post Page Associator Issues

Tags: wordpress, plugins, associations

For a client site that I am working on, the client wants to be able to associate certain custom post types to a given page. my supervisor has pointed me to the website of a previous client that did something similar. They used the Post Page Associator plugin (which seems to have been removed from the plugins list).

Here is a link to the plugin I am using: http://www.mediafire.com/?2dpbxac73rsn8l6

I've tried my best to modify the code inside the plugin to handle the custom post types I wanted to use (which the changes are included in the download). The main conflict comes from this piece of code (from the previous client's page.php file)

```
<?php 
    $sidebar = new WP_Query( $args ); //queries for posts
    $sidebar = wp_plugin_post_page_associator::get_associated_posts ($post->ID); //looks for associated posts via the plugin, the main offending line of code
    if ($sidebar!="") : while ( $sidebar->have_posts() ) : $sidebar->the_post();
    ?>
    <div id="sidebar-content"> <!-- sidebar area -->
        <h1 class="blue-text"><?php the_title(); ?></h1> <!-- the title of the associated post -->
        <div class="divider"></div>
        <?php the_content(); ?> <!-- the content of the associated post-->
        <br/><br/>
    </div>
    <?php endwhile;  else:?>

        <br/><br/>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

I was wondering if there was a way to determine what kind of post type the associated content is so I can change the WP_Query settings accordingly. If I comment out the second line of code with $sidebar, then all posts gets displayed in the sidebar. Is there a solution to this problem, or is there a better plugin for this?

Comment: I am sorry, maybe it is me , but Can you better explain what is your MAIN ultimate goal?

Comment: I want to be able to associate custom post types with pages (on the edit page screen, I can choose an entry of a custom post type to associate with it). The associated custom post type is displayed on the page in the sidebar area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a replacement plugin that does exactly what I need and shows me how to do it: http://www.cssigniter.com/ignite/custom-post-types-relationships/

Comment: Kudos for solving your own problem, but link-only answers are frowned upon at SO because they are subject to link rot. Just FYI.